# Is there a way, to prevent from precision lossing from converting from RGB, to HSV then back to RGB?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to convert color from RGB, to HSV, then back to RHB by using `UIColor`.

However, I notice there is precision losing by doing so.

This only happen in some colors.

For instance

```
import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int, a: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0,
            alpha: a
        )
    }
    
    func red() -> Int {
        var r: CGFloat = 0.0
        getRed(&r, green: nil, blue: nil, alpha: nil)
        
        let red = Int(r*0xff) & 0xff
        
        return red
    }
    
    func green() -> Int {
        var g: CGFloat = 0.0
        getRed(nil, green: &g, blue: nil, alpha: nil)
        
        let green = Int(g*0xff) & 0xff
        
        return green
    }
    
    func blue() -> Int {
        var b: CGFloat = 0.0
        getRed(nil, green: nil, blue: &b, alpha: nil)
        
        let blue = Int(b*0xff) & 0xff
        
        return blue
    }
    
    func alpha() -> Int {
        var a: CGFloat = 0.0
        getRed(nil, green: nil, blue: nil, alpha: &a)
        
        let alpha = Int(a*0xff) & 0xff
        
        return alpha
    }
}


let color = UIColor(red: 18, green: 52, blue: 86)
print("red \(color.red())")
print("green \(color.green())")
print("blue \(color.blue())")
print("alpha \(color.alpha())\n")

var h: CGFloat = 0.0
var s: CGFloat = 0.0
var v: CGFloat = 0.0
var a: CGFloat = 0.0
color.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &v, alpha: &a)
let newColor = UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: v, alpha: a)

print("new red \(newColor.red())")
print("new green \(newColor.green())")
print("new blue \(newColor.blue())")
print("new alpha \(newColor.alpha())")
```

---

I am getting output

```
red 18
green 52
blue 86
alpha 255

new red 17
new green 52
new blue 86
new alpha 255
```

---

As you can see, instead of getting original color when converting back from HSV to RGB, we are losing precision in red component color.

May I know why is it so? How can I solve such precision losing issue? Thank you.

Comment: You're losing precision because you're using 8 bits per channel. Please, please, please stop using 8 bits per channel. It is an anachronism.

Comment: @Jessy Thought that is pretty standard to use 8 bits to represent single color channel? Look at web dev, or any image editing software, 0-255 for single color channel seems like a widely used standard.

Comment: It's a holdover from when screens used 8 bits to display color channels. Today's standard is 10, backed by [halfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding errors can not be avoided when doing roundtrip color space conversions, since not all intermediate results can be represented exactly as a binary floating point number.

The problem is that with your `Int -> CGFloat` and `CGFloat -> Int` conversions, even a tiny error in the floating point value can result in an integer result which is different from the original.

In your example, the red component changes from `0.07058823529411765` to `0.07058823529411763`, which is smaller by `0.00000000000000002`. That is not much, but since you *truncate* in the conversion from floating point values to integers, the final result is one less than the original integer.

This can be demonstrated with a small stand-alone program:

```
let red = 18
var r = CGFloat(red) / 255.0
r -= 2.0E-17 // Simulate rounding error in the color calculations
let newRed = Int(r * 255)
print(newRed) // 17
```

In order to get the original integer values even after small rounding errors in the floating point calculations, it is therefore better to *round* in the conversion, in your case

```
red = Int((r * 255).rounded())
```

and similarly for the other color components.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for tips. May I know, is there any difference, if I were using Int(r * 255 + 0.5) ?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: It would make a difference for *negative* values, so that is not relevant here. You can find the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2295900-rounded. There is another function which allows to specify the rounding method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/3017985-rounded.